# MySQL Insert into another table if the value price is higher than the new price

Tags: mysql

i have a problem and doesnt find any answer that helps me :/

I have two tables.
First table is items.
It has this rows `name, isbn, siteid, price, site, link, imagelink`

The 2nd table is "deals". Has the same rows!

If there comes a new price, that is LOWER than the price that shows on "items" table for the item with the same link, than it will create a new deal on deals table.

So the `link` is what it must be the same. Every link is unique. And if the link is found and the new price i have is lower, than it must be insert into deals

Is that working in one Query?

Here was my try but not working

```
INSERT INTO deals (name, isbn, siteid, price, site, link, imagelink)
                SELECT 
                    (%s, %s, %s, REPLACE(%s, ',', '.'), %s, %s, %s)
                from items WHERE price > %s AND link = %s;
```

Comment: Where does the new price come from?

Comment: What you mean where? i give that to the query. Please check my question again, i show an example what i tried

Answer (score 1):

To answer directly: you *could* add a trigger that does this.

But in your situation, I'd say that you *shouldn't*.

Either create a view that just lists all of the values with a certain price. That has several advantages: if you want to change the price of items, you don't need to repopulate your deals table, and you're not storing redundant data.

Comment: But i need a deals table, cause the price can be changed every minutes. So if a deal is there, it shows up to few seconds, and if the price than goes back to a higher price, it is not showable anymore... so i need to make a deals table with all real deals to store them also for the future